# Which pattern is followed for the following folder structure? ( Python Project )

Tags: python-3.x, design-patterns, structure

[image]
The above structure is followed to write python code. It just grab the data from database and hit several api. Can anyone please explain the structure which has been followed here (Design pattern or something) ?

Answer (score 2):

You should use Composite Pattern for this type of problem.

```
class A:
    list_of_A = []
```

You need to ensure that the list contains only object of A class.
This way it creates a hierarchical structure.